# Locate running process location

Tags: vbscript, location, file-copying

I have a project which needs to locate a path if a certain process is running. I already have a script which specifically check and locate a specific running process and its path.

What I need to do is if, for example, the script return a value that a.exe is running in folder D:\samplefolder\a.exe, the script will just log where the exe is running, and if the startpath is not running on C:\samplefolder\a.exe then the script will start copying from "D:\samplefolder\a.exe" to  "C:\samplefolder\a.exe"

```
Function DetectExecPath

    Dim strRunningProcess, objService, strQuery, objProcess, strProcessRunning

    strProcessRunning = False

        strRunningProcess = "sample.exe"
        strQuery = "Select * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & strRunningProcess & "' "

        Set strService = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2").ExecQuery( strQuery )              

        For each objProcess in strService

            If objProcess.name = strRunningProcess  Then

                msgbox "found running" & objProcess.CommandLine

            Else

                msgbox "not running"

            End If

        Next

End Function
```

Comment: Hmmm, and also the Else statement is not working

Comment: Your query only returns the process with that given name, so there is nothing 'else' in the for loop. You can check `strService.count` instead.